# drawing circle in c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

The below code draws a circle of 3d sphere objects for me, in the x and z coords plane.

```
 double radiusCircle =0.5;
 double i;
 double j;

 for(i = 0.0f;i<6.0f;i+=0.2f){
     sphere1 = new Sphere;
     sphere1->position.x = radiusCircle *cos(i * (2.0 * 3.14) /6)+4;
     sphere1->position.z = radiusCircle *sin(i * (2.0 * 3.14) / 6 )+2;
 }
```

I am trying to stack them in the y axis as well but cant get it right.  I was wondering if someone could help me with doing this.

Basically, I want the above code which draws 30 `sphere1` in a circle but i also want to have it 4 high as well.

Comment: There are 2 ways to draw a circle that's part of a sphere. Do you want longitudinal drawing or latitudinal drawing? Or both?

Answer (score 0):

```
 double radiusCircle =0.5;
 double i;
 double j;


for (y = 0; y < 4; y++) {
     for(i = 0.0f;i<6.0f;i+=0.2f){
         sphere1 = new Sphere;
         sphere1->position.x = radiusCircle *cos(i * (2.0 * 3.14) /6)+4;
         sphere1->position.z = radiusCircle *sin(i * (2.0 * 3.14) / 6 )+2;
         sphere1->position.y = sphere1.radius * 2 * y; // <-- assign position.y to the sphere height
     }
}
```